# Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected Token A in JSON at position 3

Tags: solidity, remix

I was able to successfully deploy my first smart contract. But I am getting the runtime error. I am trying to create a new product structure for each wallet and trying to initialize the structure. As I am new I am not able to figure out what the issue is. Any help is appreciated.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Product{ 
    uint public totalProducts = 0;
    struct ProductStruct {  
        address productOwner; 
        uint productId;
        string uniqueName;  
        string platform;
        uint aspect1Score;
        uint aspect2Score;
        uint aspect3Score;
        uint aspect4Score;
        uint aspect5Score;
        uint totalScore;
    }

    mapping(uint => ProductStruct) public ProductStructs;

    function setProduct (string memory _productName, string memory _platform) public {
        totalProducts ++;
        ProductStruct storage newProduct = ProductStructs[totalProducts];
        newProduct.productOwner = msg.sender;
        newProduct.productId = totalProducts;
        newProduct.uniqueName = _productName;
        newProduct.platform = _platform;
        newProduct.aspect1Score = 100;
        newProduct.aspect2Score = 100;
        newProduct.aspect3Score = 100;
        newProduct.aspect4Score = 100;
        newProduct.aspect5Score = 100;
        newProduct.totalScore = 500;
    }

    function getProduct(uint _productId) public view returns (string memory _uniqueName) {
        _productId = totalProducts;
        return ProductStructs[_productId].uniqueName;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to share the full error and where it came from. Were you using code to call your contract? Some tool? The issue almost certainly has nothing to do with your Solidity code.